# producing an empty zip file java

Tags: java, zip

I'm currently writing a function what would create a zip file, which will be used in other functionality. Below it is my function's code:

```
public void createZip(){

        try{
            String outfile = this.filename + ".zip";
            //input file
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(this.filename);
            //output file
            ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outfile));
            //name the file inside the zip file
            System.out.println(this.filename);
            zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(this.filename));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[this.BUFFER];
            int len;
            //copy the file to the zip
            while((len= input.read(buffer)) > 0){
                System.out.println(len);
                zip.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            zip.closeEntry();
            zip.flush();
            input.close();
            zip.close();
            this.filename += ".zip";
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I have tried to debug, but I couldn't find the source of this problem. The function runs without any further problems, but the zip file produced it is an empty one.

Comment: You never use the `filename` parameter of the method, and instead you use the global filename field in the containing class.  That might not be the solution, but it definitely seems like a potential issue, and it's bad convention to have unused parameters regardless.

Comment: @Vulcan I assume it's just a bad design, seeing how he manipulates this.filename inside this method, it may very well be that he set it before entering the method, completely ignoring the parameter.

Comment: @Vulcan I had a version that used filename as an arguement, but I changed the design and forgot to remove that.

Comment: Hi, You were able to solve the problem. The same thing is happening to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must close the entry using [ZipOutputStream#closeEntry()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#closeEntry%28%29) prior to closing the output stream, or the entry is never confirmed to have been written entirely.

Also, the name of the ZipEntry cannot be the entire path; i.e, it should be `dog.png` instead of `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\dog.png`.  This issue will pass by without an exception, and will cause the data from the file to be compressed directly into the zip, rather than into the zip as a compressed file.

Comment: Worth noting that all these close() calls need to be handled in case of IOException too.

Comment: I have used your suggestion, however, the zip file is still empty

Comment: @philippe What is `this.filename`? I notice that it's having .zip appending to it to create a zip file, which implies that it may be a directory.  If that's true, you simply have logistical flaws, as directory contents cannot be written in that way; rather, once you put a directory entry, then you put separate entries for each file within that directory, and write those as you are now.

Comment: @Vulcan this.filename is the name of the file, if it is not a zip file. I'm just adding .zip to the end of the file. As of now it is only supposed to compress a single file. For the case it is a directory, I will change the algorithm to iterate over the directory, creating each entry on the zip file as supposed. The zip file being produced it is still empty :-(

Comment: @Vulcan, OK think what happens when `input.read(buffer)` throws IOException. Will any of those close() calls be made?

Comment: @philippe I've just ran the code, and I noticed that the data is being written to the zip file (it's size increased by the file size), but the file is not being written as a file within the zip; rather, as a part of the zip itself.

Comment: @maksimov Of course not, but I'm answering the question, which is asking why no file is written to the zip.

Comment: @Vulcan Do you think it's a naming issue them?

Comment: @philippe I'm not sure to be honest; I've modified the names to be relative rather than absolute and I've made the zip entry name completely different than the zip itself, among other things, but the same still occurs.  Furthermore, in doing research, every zip-writing tutorial contain code near-exact to yours.

Comment: [Figured it out](http://textu.be/9).  It was because of the name of the zip entry; it cannot be the absolute path, it needs to be the relative path.  When I tried relative path earlier, I forgot to remove the leading backslash.

Comment: @Vulcan could you please edit your question so I can vote that as solved?

Comment: Misnaming the entry doesn't bypass compression. All it does is provide inconvenience when *unzipping.*

Answer (score 3):

```
final static byte[] EmptyZip={80,75,05,06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00};
public static void createEmptyZip(String path){
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        fos.write(EmptyZip, 0, 22);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

well, just wondering why you pass a filename as a parameter if you dont use it within the code.. 
Since you are always using the this.filename. That makes me think that you are trying to name a zip file with a name you set into the objects state and since you are also using that same name in the ZipEntry its trying to add that same zipper file inside it.. since the ZipEntry must point to an existing file, thats why it comes up empty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is the output:
File name: C:/Users/souzamor/workspace/xmlparser/src/PR_training.docx
File size: 306

Comment: so the entry being created points to an existing file, that's what I use in zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(this.filename));

Comment: i see, i got confused over there in how you were using this.namefile and the namefile argument wasnt even used so i assumed that you were pointing by mistake at a file that didnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush the buffer by using zip.flush() before closing, although close should flush the buffer.

Also verify this.filename.  You have a local variable with the same name.  The local variable filename is never used.  It's possible the zip file is being written to a different location than what you expect.

Comment: Very strange usage of `filename` and `this.filename` indeed. Was going to write an answer about this, but am not gonna bother ;)

Comment: The lack of flushing is most likely not the issue; the issue is that the entry is never closed, so the pointer is never confirmed to have written an entry.

Comment: @maksimov I had another version that used the filename, but I decided to adopt this.filename instead and forgot to update the function. I'm sorry, doing three internships this summer.

Answer (score 0):

@phillipe try this please

```
    public void createZip(String filename) {
    try {
        //input file
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
        //output file
        ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename + ".zip"));
        //name the file inside the zip file
        zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        //copy the file to the zip
        while((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            System.out.println();
            zip.write(buffer, 0 , len);
        }
        zip.closeEntry();
        zip.flush();
        zip.close();
        input.close();
        filename += ".zip";
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

those code create a zip file and that's work and for me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Make one manual directory in `ZipEntry` without File Separator.

```
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("LOG" + fileName));
```

instead of

```
zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName));
```

Here `fileName = file.getAbsoluteFile();`

This will first create LOG dir in zip file followed by fileNames with directory path. This avoids creating initial empty directory in zip file.